# How can I center this CSS menu?

Tags: html, css

I've tried many methods but cannot get this menu centered .. Any ideas?

You can view the page here:
http://jsbin.com/obecig/1/edit

I tried text-align:center in the #nav ul selector but no luck..

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#nav, .nav, #nav .nav li { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
#nav li {float:left; display:inline; cursor:pointer; list-style:none; padding:0px 10px 0px 10px; border:1px #000 solid; position:relative;}
#nav li ul.first {left:-1px; top:100%;}

li, li a {color:#000;}
#nav .nav li { width:100%; text-indent:10px; line-height:30px; margin-right:10px; border-top:1px #000 solid; border-bottom:1px #000 solid; border-left:none; border-right:none; background:#fff;}
#nav li a {display:block; width:inherit; height:inherit;}

ul.nav { display:none; }
#nav li:hover > a, #nav li:hover { color:#fff; background:#000; }
li:hover > .nav { display:block; position:absolute; width:200px; top:-2px; left:50%; z-index:1000; border:1px #000 solid;}
li:hover { position:relative; z-index:2000; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul id="nav">
    <li>Menu 1
        <ul class="nav first">
            <li>Menu 1</li>
            <li>Menu 2</li>
            <li>Menu 3</li>
            <li>Menu 4</li>
        <ul>
    </li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
</ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing how everyone answered the same thing and no one bothered to explain why... here we go:

As you all know, centering a block level element can be a pain when you don't know how. First of all, most of us know that `margin: 0 auto;` works, but not everyone knows why.

A quick breakdown of `margin: 0 auto;` has to do with the way CSS accepts shorthand notation for certain properties. Saying `margin` you are of course targeting the margin of the given element and the `0` part is using shorthand notation to say: 0 on the top and 0 on the bottom ... while adding `auto` at the end you are saying: auto margin on the left and auto margin on the right.

The above will not work if you don't have a defined width for the element in question. In this case the element has an ID attribute of `#nav` ... this is why the examples that everyone gave in their answers have a fixed width. The logic behind this is that a block level element extends 100% of it's parent container by default unless you specifically define otherwise in your CSS.

So in theory this also works for centering, and while it's more markup and not the best approach for simplicity's sake, I'm only showing it for illustrative purposes.

```
#nav {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Everyone is more used to looking at it like this... and we use it like this because it's shorter.

```
#nav {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The zero is not a must... Remember that it's the top and bottom margin of your element. So with that said, here's an example of the element with a 20 pixel margin on the bottom and centered.

```
#nav {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}
```

Last but not least... The shorthand notation for this property (`margin`) is the same as for the: `border` , `padding` , etc. It stars from Top... going clockwise to Left with Right and Bottom in between the two.

So it's: top, right, bottom, left. Like so: `margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px`

Answer (score 1):

You need to give it a width, and then set the horizontal margins to auto. That's the quickest way anyways.

add this to your css:

```
#nav
{
     width:100px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To center something, it needs a width, and margin: 0 auto, so if you add this code:

```
#nav { 
  width: 100px; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

It should (and did for me) work

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav{
 width:80px;
 margin: 0 auto;}
```